# Why LET doesn't work with VECTOR?

Tags: clojure

Instead of

```
(let [x 1] (my-expression))
```

I'm trying to use:

```
(let (vector x 1) (my-expression))
```

Don't ask why, I just like normal brackets more. But Clojure says:

```
let requires a vector for its binding in ...
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [let special form](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--%28let%20%5bbindings%2a%20%5d%20exprs%2a%29) [binding form](http://clojure.org/special_forms#binding-forms) is required to be a vector *literal* not just an expression that would evaluate to a vector.

Why? Roughly stated, the expression must be compiled before it can be evaluated. At compile-time `(vector x 1)` will not have been evaluated to a `vector`, it will just be a list. Indeed if it were to be evaluated, the arguments of `vector` would be evaluated, meaning `x` would have to be resolved. But, you don't want `x` to be resolved, you want it bound.

Comment: Watch David McNeil's [Macros are Hard!](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Clojure-Macros) presentation for a progressively deeper look into how the reader and evaluator work.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [source](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/let#source) for the `let` macro

```
(defmacro let
  "binding => binding-form init-expr

  Evaluates the exprs in a lexical context in which the symbols in
  the binding-forms are bound to their respective init-exprs or parts
  therein."
  {:added "1.0", :special-form true, :forms '[(let [bindings*] exprs*)]}
  [bindings & body]
  (assert-args let
     (vector? bindings) "a vector for its binding"
     (even? (count bindings)) "an even number of forms in binding vector")
  `(let* ~(destructure bindings) ~@body))
```

You'll notice that the `bindings` argument is not evaluated when the macro tries to ensure it was given correct arguments via `assert-args`.

At the point when clojure evaluates `(vector? bindings)` , `bindings` is a form (`list`) containing  a `fn` as the first element followed by it's arguments and therefore is not a `vector` at that point.

Answer (score 3):

`let` requires a vector for it's bindings (at compile time) so trying to put a vector functional call in its place won't work (as that will only produce a vector at runtime).

However you can make your own let with a bit of macro-fu:

```
(defmacro mylet [bindings & exprs]
  `(let ~(vec bindings) ~@exprs))

(mylet (x 1) (inc x))
=> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This code, for example, does work:

```
(eval `(let ~(vector 'a 1) (println ~'a)))
```

which means you could write your own let macro that accepts a list instead of a vector. This would be quite bad for your overall Clojure experience and I wouldn't advise it.